# Lesson : Solving System of Equations using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix
$$
A =  \begin{pmatrix}
  a & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & b & 5 \\
  -3 & 1 & b
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
in my try, I came up with $$ bx1 = 0,\quad x2 + 5/a x3 = 0,\quad x2 + a x3 = 0
$$
The question is to find all possible choices of $a$, and $b$, that would make the matrix singular.

Comment: Are you familiar with determinants? Specifically, the fact that a matrix is singular if and only if its determinant is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant is $a(b^2-5)$, so the matrix is singular if $a=0$ or if $b=\pm\sqrt 5$.

You can also see this without referring to the determinant.  If $a=0$, then the top row is all zeros, so the matrix is singular.  If $a\neq 0$, then the first row is clearly not in the space spanned by columns 2 and 3.  Therefore, the only way you'll get a singular matrix is when those two columns are linearly dependent (scalar multiples of one another).  This happens when the ratios of coordinates are the same: $b/1=5/b$, i.e. $b^2=5$.

Comment: Thanks. I had been trying to solve the system, using row echelon, and kept getting some weird looking results.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ is singular if and only if its determinant is $0$. The determinant of $A$ is isn’t hard to calculate; it turns out to be a very simple function of $a$ and $b$. If you set that expression to $0$ and factor it, you should be able to determine quite easily what values of $a$ and $b$ make it $0$.

**Added:** $$\det A = \left| \begin{array}{c}
  a & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & b & 5 \\
  -3 & 1 & b
 \end{array}\right|=
a\left|\begin{array}{c}
b&5\\1&b
\end{array}\right|=a(b^2-5)\;.$$

(There is also a shortcut for calculating the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix that you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#3-by-3_matrices); it gives $ab^2-5a$, which is then readily factored to $a(b^2-5)$.)

Comment: @RacMain It's $a \times {\rm det}\pmatrix{b & 5 \\ 1 & b}.$ Can you compute that?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce by rows (or columns: whatever) your matrix. It will be singular iff at least one of the rows (columns) becomes ***all zeroes*** at some point.

Comment: I tried to do just that and had a hard time figuring it out, so I decided to ask for help with it instead.